# Dynamic programming: modified Knapsack

Tags: c#, floating, knapsack-problem

I am trying to solve a variation on the knapsack problem using dynamic programming:

So what I have is a field of squares with dimensions: N*N (like a chessboard). On each square I have some values. What I can do is to add one (+1) to the value on the square or remove one (-1). There is a special rule which says that if there are neighboring squares (squares which have common side - diagonal squares don't count) that have a value equal to the new value of the square, then the values of all such neighboring squares are set to zero

The goal is to decrease the total value of all squares as much as possible.

For example if I have a matrix 3x3 representing a field with 3*3 squares then we can have something like this:

```
int[3,3] field = { 1, 2, 3,
                   5, 1, 6,
                   7, 3, 9 }
```

and now if I decrease with one the element [0, 1] which has a value of two, then all the elements [0, 0] [0, 1] and [1, 1] will set their values to 0.

So basically what have I done till now is to rate each action for each square and with some depth of the actions (meaning that I have calculated the rating if one action is repeated several times on one square) and I hold these ratings in a four dimensional array, `ratings[action, depth, row, col]`.

The rating represents the number by which the total value of the squares will be decreased.

What I want is to find the optimal sequence of actions that will remove as much as possible values from the field. And this must happen in predefined number of actions (or there are defined number of turns and I can make only one action each turn). And with the last said it is clear that I have to find which combination of subsets of the depths from the ratings of the squares will give me highest total rating.

First I thought that this can be done with subset sum problem and after that sort the received list of items by their ratings but after that I realized that this can be realized with the knapsack problem except that the ratings are dependent from each other and here is where my problem comes. For example if there is square that changes its value then it is possible that its neighbouring squares can change their ratings automatically. I can write a method for checking if the neighbours of the square will change their ratings after the action but this is not what is troubling me. What worries me is how to realize the knapsack problem with changing values (ratings of the squares)?

To summarize what I have so far:

- I have a defined number of turns (actions) C - which can be represented as the maximal weight of the matrix
- I have depth of actions for each square (from 1 to C) - which can be represented as the weight for each item
- I have ratings for all of the squares (non-negative integer number) - which can be represented as the values of the items.

The main problem for me is that the value of the items that are going to be put in the knapsack can change depending on which items are kept.

I have to admit that I didn't wrote my knapsack algorithm from scratch but rather than that I used an already written one and transformed it for my needs. I get the algorithm from here: http://sriwantha.blogspot.com/2011/07/knapsack-problem-in-c.html

And here is my code:

```
//Knapsack problem:

//class for the items in the knapsack
public class Item 
{
    public int row;
    public int col;
    public int action;
    public int depth;
    public int rating;
    public Item(int row, int col, int action, int depth, int rating)
    {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
        this.action = action;
        this.depth = depth;
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "row,col,action=" + row + "," + col + "," + action + ", depth=" + depth + ", rating=" + rating;
    }
}

class KnapSackProblem
{
    public static List<Item> FindItemsToPack(List<Item> items, int depthCapacity, out int totalRatingValue)
    {
        int[,] ratings = new int[items.Count + 1, depthCapacity + 1];
        bool[,] keep = new bool[items.Count + 1, depthCapacity + 1];

        for (int i = 1; i <= items.Count; i++)
        {
            Item currentItem = items[i - 1];
            for (int depth = 1; depth <= depthCapacity; depth++)
            {
                if (depth >= currentItem.depth)
                {
                    int remainingDepth = depth - currentItem.depth;
                    int remainingDepthRating = 0;
                    if (remainingDepth > 0)
                    {
                        remainingDepthRating = ratings[i - 1, remainingDepth];
                    }
                    int currentItemTotalRating = currentItem.rating + remainingDepthRating;
                    if (currentItemTotalRating > ratings[i - 1, depth])
                    {
                        keep[i, depth] = true;
                        ratings[i, depth] = currentItemTotalRating;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        keep[i, depth] = false;
                        ratings[i, depth] = ratings[i - 1, depth];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        List<Item> itemsToBePacked = new List<Item>();

        int remainDepth = depthCapacity;
        int item = items.Count;
        while (item > 0)
        {
            bool toBePacked = keep[item, remainDepth];
            if (toBePacked)
            {
                itemsToBePacked.Add(items[item - 1]);
                remainDepth = remainDepth - items[item - 1].depth;
            }
            item--;
        }

        totalRatingValue = ratings[items.Count, depthCapacity];
        return itemsToBePacked;
    }
}
```

And from another method I'm calling the Knapsack algorithm:

```
List<Item> actionsToDo = new List<Item>();
Item newItemTake;
Item newItemAdd;

for (int depth = 0; depth < maxDepth; depth++)
    {
    for (int row = 0; row < dimension; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < dimension; col++)
        {
            if (ratings[Take, depth, row, col] >= 0)
            {
                newItemTake = new Item(row, col, Take, depth + 1, ratings[Take, depth, row, col]);
                actionsToDo.Add(newItemTake);
            }
            if (ratings[Add, depth, row, col] >= 0)
            {
                newItemAdd = new Item(row, col, Add, depth + 1, ratings[Add, depth, row, col]);
                actionsToDo.Add(newItemAdd);
            }
        }
    }
}

int totalRating = 0;

List<Item> itemsToBePacked = KnapSackProblem.FindItemsToPack(actionsToDo, maxDepth, out totalRating);

foreach (var item in itemsToBePacked)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
Console.WriteLine(totalRating);
```

Comment: First step: edit your post and format 'as code' only sections which refer to code (ctrl-k to format as code). It's terribly difficult to read as it stands. Secondly, modify your question so it read less like a dissertation. Distill it to the basic question.

Comment: @Michael that is not the way to do this. If you're going to leave comments such as these, then _you_ edit the question. If you want him to cut something out, then you should offer a second edit which removes those things (there's a two minute window on coalescing edits, I believe, that should be enough to clean up the question some and spend time on edits). Remember, snark is easy, help is hard. You're here to offer help, not to offer snark. If you've forgotten, maybe a ban will encourage you to play nice?

Comment: Simeon, it _is_ rather tricky to determine why this is broken, can you highlight more specifically what you need help with? In addition, I would point out that your corners (given the `1` in the center) look like the place with the most room to lose, and the `3` in the bottom middle will most restrict the values, if you don't go below zero. Otherwise, you can use the corners to go below zero on the sides, then use the middle to bring the sides back to positive, I think.